# How to get uiCollectionView original asset or image when selected and how to pass it back to previous viewcontroller and load to imageView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, phassetcollection

I have a collection view to feed one imageView on the main viewController.
I have three problems:

1-I am forced to use "highQualityFormat"in collectionView because I can not get the original image on didSeleect function.is there any way to get the original image?

2- in phAssetCollection we can not use sortDescriptors with creationDate.how can I sort images? startDate & endDate not worked.

3-How can I load the selected image in the first uiviewController instead of using userManager.shared and notificationCenter.
Thank you for your attention.

The main viewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var frontpic: UIImageView!

@IBAction func openPictureDialog(_ sender: Any) {
        if !isLoadSoNew(){return}
        selectedPic = 1
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
          let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "collectionVc1")//
          present(vc,animated: true,completion: nil)
}

@objc func fillFront(_ notification:Notification){
             
            frontpic.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            frontpic.image = UserManager.shared.collectionViewImage       
     
     }
```

The uicollectionView:

```
import UIKit
import Photos
class collectionVewControl: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView1: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView1.delegate = self
        collectionView1.dataSource = self
        fetchCustomAlbumPhotos()
        collectionView1.frame.size.height = view.frame.height-60
    }
    var imageArray = [UIImage]()
    var photo: UIImage? @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }

    
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        UserManager.shared.collectionViewImage = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "fillFront"), object: nil)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
    func fetchCustomAlbumPhotos()
    {
        var albumName = "APKSoft"
        var assetCollection = PHAssetCollection()
        var photoAssets = PHFetchResult<AnyObject>()
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)
       // fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

        let collection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
        if let firstObject = collection.firstObject{
            //found the album
            assetCollection = firstObject
        }
        else {
             albumName = "Recents"
            if let firstObject = collection.firstObject{
                assetCollection = firstObject
            }
        }
        _ = collection.count
        photoAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection, options: nil) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>
        let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()
        photoAssets.enumerateObjects{(object: AnyObject!,
            count: Int,
            stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in

            if object is PHAsset{
                let asset = object as! PHAsset
               // print("Inside  If object is PHAsset, This is number 1")

                let imageSize = CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth,
                                       height: asset.pixelHeight)

                /* For faster performance, and maybe degraded image */
                let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
                options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
                options.isSynchronous = true

                imageManager.requestImage(for: asset,
                                                  targetSize: imageSize,
                                                  contentMode: .aspectFill,
                                                  options: options,
                                                  resultHandler: {
                                                    (image, info) -> Void in
                                                    self.photo = image!
                                                    /* The image is now available to us */
                                                    self.addImgToArray(uploadImage: self.photo!)
                                                  //  print("enum for image, This is number 2")

                })

            }
        }
    }

    func addImgToArray(uploadImage:UIImage)
    {
        self.imageArray.append(uploadImage)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the second part of my own question.
I had to use fetchOption for phAsset not phAssetCollection and this was my mistake.

```
_ = collection.count
        fetchOptions1.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        photoAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection, options: fetchOptions1) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi I can answer your third question now, I am not sure for the others.

You can use protocol and delegate for passing image to previous view controller.

You can check this [Medium post](https://medium.com/@astitv96/passing-data-between-view-controllers-using-delegate-and-protocol-ios-swift-4-beginners-e32828862d3f) out.